Has there been a randomized sampling in experiments for Elitzur–Vaidman bomb tester?
I was reading Elitzur–Vaidman bomb tester wikipedia page and I wanted to understand it better. The language of original idea is IMO not precise, e.g.

Consider a collection of light-sensitive bombs, of which some are duds. When their triggers detect any light, even a single photon, the light is absorbed and the bomb explodes.

But what is the probability of detection when photon's wave function goes through the trigger? Anyway, I wanted to read about actual experiment as claimed:

In 1994, Anton Zeilinger, Paul Kwiat, Harald Weinfurter, and Thomas Herzog performed an equivalent of the above experiment, proving interaction-free measurements are indeed possible.14

I've read the paper. I have not seen how they prepared ramdomized sample of two types of objects (as equivalent of real vs. dud bombs) and checked if objects were changed, only that:

here we define the "object" to be the mirror + detector system

Am I misunderstanding something or is the experiment far from a rigorous one? Maybe other papers present better experiments (clearer descriptions), if so, please cite them in the answer. TIA
P.S. I've seen The Validity of the Data Set of the Elitzur-Vaidman Quantum Bomb Tester Experiment, the  question is about rate of photons generation.

You write "The language of original idea is IMO not precise" but the text you quote after that comes from Wikipedia, hence not necessarily reproduced from the original EV bomb paper. Additionally, even if that text or a similar one is present in the original paper, it doesn't mean that a precise description isn't given as well. It is often the case as you probably know that the introductory part of a paper will be less formal and precise, and the idea is stated more technically often in what follows the introductory part.

@Amit, thank you. I've looked at original paper and it consists of two parts - one is detecting presence of the object and second is about bombs. The actual experiment seems to be about 1st part. I plan to rethink my question.

Yes, the bombs part is mainly meant to "dramatically illustrate" the underlying ideas :) You're welcome.

@Amit, I saw no proof of 2nd if 1st is correct. Is there? Maybe it is obvious to experts...

I'm no expert, but I have read the original paper quite a while ago. I don't want to give you a partially correct answer (and the comments aren't meant for that anyway), but I do recall that essentially the 2nd part with the bombs is just a specific implementation of the more general setup described prior to that. It will be naturally more difficult to implement experimentally, but as to the why and what, I can't really tell. I only remember that "dud bombs" and "real bombs" can essentially be replaced with the analogous pair of "disconnected detector" and "functioning detector".

@Amit, after some more of reading the paper and pondering I think 1) it is a misnomer to call this tester "interaction-free". There is an interaction, though not photon absorption 2) the bomb part is still written not precise "if a single photon hits the sensor, the bomb explodes.". What hitting means? For tester to work it may mean the same: "photon is absorbed". It such case a tester is the same as 1st part. I'm inclined to close the question and plan to do so if there will be no answers during nearest time.
